# Does multiple requests to a REST service (Spring Boot & Java) create a new object of a class while mapping it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, microservices

So I just built a basic web service using spring-boot by defining a rest controller and a few request mappings. I have initialized an object of a class in my controller. I'm using this object to call other methods I've used in various request mappings.

My question is, will multiple requests to this web service use the same object or does a new one gets created each time?

Comment: Can you show your code? It depends on how the object is created.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the object is being created in the method/s that executes your web service or if it is a field in your controller class.  If it is a field in your controller class, then it will not be recreated with each subsequent request.  But if it is being created in one of your methods being executed within the request, then it will be recreated with each request.